# Filter out Azure Front Door health probe requests from Application Gateway metrics

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

I've deployed AFD in front of several application gateways (for geolocation load balancing, specifically), now my Application Gateway metrics are bombarded by requests from AFD, and I'd like to filter those out.
Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the two options mentioned below:

1. Set high health probe interval on Azure Front Door's backend pool configuration for not sending frequent health probe check. Azure Front Door will not send frequent health probe request on the Application Gateway.
2. Disable the health probe on Azure Front Door (Not recommended at all).